# My overhead door sticks at very beginning of open cycle

Tags: garage-door-opener

I recently insulated my garage door with a foam kit and I don't think it weighs much at all.  I believe the culprit is the weatherstripping I added to the the frame.  I think it is creating a vacuum that is hard for the opener to fix.  If the door sits for a while, it struggles to start the opening process.  Once it is moving it is fine, but there is an initial jolt that shakes the door and the worm drive track pretty good.

1. Are my suspicions correct?
2. Is the weather stripping too tight so the door needs backed away a bit on the track, or does the spring need wound a few turns?

Comment: Does the door stick if you pull the release on the opener and open it by hand?

Comment: Did the door do this before you added insulation? When you added insulation was anything removed, loosened, or tightened?

Comment: I forgot to test the door operation manually this morning.   I will try this.

Comment: I think the changepoint has been warm weather, so the seal is stronger as it is more flexible.  I did tighten stuff and changed rollers, but everything worked well until the lately.  All winter it was fine.

Comment: First rule of garage doors. Unhook the mechanical opener and work the door manually so you can feel it.

Comment: I knew that but got ahead of myself with the post.

Comment: UPDATE: I can open the door manually, but it required a lot of muscle.  The door also does not stay balanced when a foot or two open.  I imagine the spring needs wound more now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know answering my own question may be frowned upon, but I have gone many months dealing with this issue and through trial error, I have found what worked best for me.

I had to re-apply silicone spray every couple of weeks to keep the door from sticking to the weatherstripping.  It could go a month if the weather was cold.  A balmy day with the sun shining would make it stick.  I washed and degreased the door and weatherstripping as well before applying the spray.  This was not a very repeatable solution.  I would have to buy a can of spray more than once per year.  I can't adjust the door either.  Where it sticks, the door distance is set.

I have had no problem since December after applying baby powder.  I made a paste with water and brushed it on every square inch of the weatherstripping.  It is easily the best thing I have tried.

Update: Make sure it is talcum powder, not corn starch. A paste of corn starch has other worldly properties.

Comment: Could that be because it's winter?

Comment: It has been super mild here in Ohio. In fact temperatures in the 60s.  I was having issues until I used the baby powder fix. Even 40 degree days could give me trouble is the sun was shining bright. Summer was worse.

Comment: Someone should tell DuPont that baby powder beats Teflon.  :)

Comment: I think it is because the baby powder goes on thick on some spots and acts as a reservoir.

Comment: Answering your own question is entirely appropriate in some cases. Please accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

If your weatherstripping was installed firmly to the door, the problem is probably simple static friction. In total, the seal creates a substantial drag on the door, which is enhanced by warm weather making the seal softer and stickier.

I'd try applying a drying, not-greasy lubricant to the weather stripping--silicone or Teflon. Alternatively, adjust the depth of the door rail brackets slightly to reduce the pressure of the door against the seal.

Comment: Won't the lubricant attract dirt?  I have a white door of course.

Comment: @EvilElf spray on a little lube; wipe down w/ rag.  The remaining amount (not that silicone collects much dirt to begin with) will be fine.  Whatever you do, do **NOT** use WD40

Comment: Right. That's what I meant by "drying" and "non-greasy". Something that doesn't attract dirt (as much). How you apply it depends on what it is (and some common sense). Carl has a good suggestion.

Comment: I can't adjust the top and bottom most track points as they are connect with rivets.  I sprayed silicone on the weather stripping and it worked great for a couple of days and then it started to stick a little again, but not as much as before.  I sprayed some more on this morning.  I think I am going to have to replace the weather stripping at some point as it is just so close to the door that it is producing a lot of friction.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there's no plane position adjustment in your track kit. I've never encountered one like you describe. Even if there is, replacement brackets with depth adjustment would be very inexpensive.